# @RequestMapping without parameter in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to understand my project Code while learning Spring MVC.

In spring `@RequestMapping` annotation takes parameters. For example,

```
@RequestMapping(value="/something", method=RequestMethod.POST)
@RequestMapping(value="/index.html", method=RequestMethod.GET)
@RequestMapping("/index")
@RequestMapping(params="command=GETINFO")
```

My project uses annotations and it doesn't use any XML for mapping. I have a below structure of Controller.

```
@Controller
public class RuleStepController {
   private static final String ATTRIBUTE_BRANCH = "branch";
    private static final String ATTRIBUTE_EDIT_FORM = "editForm";
 .................
    @Autowired
    private RuleStepService ruleStepService;
    @Autowired
    private PopulationDao populationDao;

     @RequestMapping
    public void ruleStepEntForm(Long populationId, ModelMap model) {
     .....
     editForm.setStepEnt(stepDto);
    }

@RequestMapping
    public void ruleStepOrgCount(RuleStepOrgSearchForm searchForm, ModelMap model){
      .......
model.addAttribute("searchForm", searchForm);
    }

@RequestMapping
    public String ruleStepMgrForm() {
        logger.debug(String.format("ruleStepMgrForm"));
        return "forward:/employee/employeeSearchForm.view?relationshipId=0&roleId=0&formId=stepMgr";
    }
```

I would like to understand what would be significance of `@RequestMapping` when it doesn't carry any parameter?

What is use of `@AutoWired` ?

Comment: when @RequestMapping without any parameters is used on a method, then it uses the parameters of the method to identify the input parameters from the GET/POST request. E.g. in your `ruleStepEntForm` method, the parameter in GET/POST should be named `populationId`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. With annotation `@RequestMapping` you can bind request parameters with several way:

   URI Template Patterns, use annotation `@PathVariable`

   ```
   @RequestMapping(value="/owners/{ownerId}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
   public String findOwner(@PathVariable String ownerId, Model model) {
       Owner owner = ownerService.findOwner(ownerId);
       model.addAttribute("owner", owner);
       return "displayOwner";
   }
   ```

   Request Parameters and Header Values

   ```
   @Controller
   @RequestMapping("/owners/{ownerId}")
   public class RelativePathUriTemplateController {

       @RequestMapping(value = "/pets/{petId}", method = RequestMethod.GET, params = "myParam=myValue")
       public void findPet(@PathVariable String ownerId, @PathVariable String petId, Model model) {
           // implementation omitted
       }
   }
   ```

   use `@RequestParam`

   ```
   @Controller
   @RequestMapping("/pets")
   @SessionAttributes("pet")
   public class EditPetForm {

       @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
       public String setupForm(@RequestParam("petId") int petId, ModelMap model) {
           Pet pet = this.clinic.loadPet(petId);
           model.addAttribute("pet", pet);
           return "petForm";
       }
   }
   ```

   Mapping the request body with the `@RequestBody` annotation

   ```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/something", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
   public void handle(@RequestBody String body, Writer writer) throws IOException {
       writer.write(body);
   }
   ```
2. Autowiring

   ```
   @Autowired
   private RuleStepService ruleStepService;
   ```

   The Spring Container has created the bean `ruleStepService` before. If you need use this bean in your class you only need declare as above and the container will inject the bean into your class . You don't need declare like;

   ```
   RuleStepService ruleStepService =new RuleStepService().
   ```

   Container will find the bean name `ruleStepService` or the bean has type `RuleStepService` ( based on the strategy in configuration )

Answer (score 0):

@RequestMapping annotation used in Controllers allow us not only to implement URL pattern matching but also to extract variables from the request URL itself.So you have to have a @RequestMapping either you have parameter or not.By default, the HTTP method mapped by a @RequestMapping is GET

Here are 2 good references from spring source:

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html

**AutoWiring**

here is the helpful link

http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/05/08/spring-beans-autowiring-concepts/

Comment: So, given the OP's presented code, which pattern of URIs (GET requests), will be processed by the `ruleStepOrgCount` method?

Comment: A GET method that has no additional mapping is mapped to the root of the controller-mapping itself.

Comment: I know. But in this case the `@Controller` does not itself have a `@RequestMapping`. So, what is *its* URI pattern?